# What parameters are required to share content from my BlackBerry WebWorks Application via Twitter's native BlackBerry implementation using Invoke?

Tags: javascript, blackberry, twitter, invoke, blackberry-webworks

I am displaying a list of tweets in my BlackBerry WebWorks application that the user should be able to share via Twitter.

I want to use Twitter's native BlackBerry client, and am calling it via an invoke object. I can launch the Twitter application fine, but does anyone know what parameters are needed to skip directly to sharing content from my application?

I am using the following to successfully invoke the Twitter client:

```
 try{

    var params = new Array();

    var args = new blackberry.invoke.JavaArguments('net_rim_bb_twitter', params);

    blackberry.invoke.invoke(blackberry.invoke.APP_JAVA, args);
 }catch(e){
    alert("Could Not Invoke App: "+e.name+" : "+e.message);
 }
```

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 0):

From WebWorks in order to invoke other application you need to use JavaArguments (as you do), but don't add parameters as it won't work use only module name:

```
new blackberry.invoke.JavaArguments('net_rim_bb_twitter');
```

This way the code will try to invoke 'net_tim_bb_twitter'.
Looking in BB's github and how JavaArguments are implemented - it takes the first parameter and creates a URL query from the Array arguments. If you add parameters like ["par=val","par2=val2"] then the code will try to start 'net_rim_bb_twitter?par=val&par2=val2" which won't start anything if not specified by the OS or the app. The idea with parameter is to invoke apps that are listening for URLs.

Using without parameters will just start the app but it won't prefill the desired fields within the app, so you need to create a screen in your app to post to twitter or just use the web intents https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents and BrowserArguments to start nice little twitter web app prefilled with data from your web app.